# Returning a value in a column based on a specific time range in another column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create a function to return one of FOUR separate values(20:00-03:59 = LATE; 04:00-09:59 = MORNING; 10:00-14:59 = AFTERNOON; 15:00-19:59 = EVENING) in a new column based on a time-range from another column. For example, if the time in column "start_time" is between 04:00-09:59, I would like the function to return MORNING in column "period_of_day". Thank you.

[Link to sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u_tC11sASBesw3sFS14zCOP4QoyqJdX_2xYyEtpY2k4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: More information is needed (i.e., the exact breakdowns of times you consider to constitute each of your three periods). In addition, please include a link to your sample spreadsheet as, otherwise, you'd be expecting the volunteer contributors here to set up their own spreadsheet and manually enter data before they could even begin to consider a solution.

Comment: 20:00-03:59 = LATE; 04:00-09:59 = MORNING; 10:00-14:59 = AFTERNOON; 15:00-19:59 = EVENING. [Sheets Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u_tC11sASBesw3sFS14zCOP4QoyqJdX_2xYyEtpY2k4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: So FOUR values, not THREE? And up to 10:00 AM is MORNING, not 9:30? (I recommend changing your post to reflect this.) In the meantime, I'll take a look and report back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need your current Column E at all (unless you just like seeing that time isolated). It's not necessary for the Col-F formula's use.

For now, delete *all* of Column F (including the header) and paste the following in F1:

`=ArrayFormula({"period_of_day";IF(D2:D="",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(MOD(D2:D,1),{TIME(0,0,0),"LATE";TIME(4,0,0),"MORNING";TIME(10,0,0),"AFTERNOON";TIME(15,0,0),"EVENING";TIME(20,0,0),"LATE"},2,TRUE)))})`

This will produce the header and all results for all rows.

As I say, after this formula is in your sheet, you really can just delete Column E altogether as it is unnecessary. And with the amount of data you're dealing with, you should keep things as trim as possible for best results (including deleting unused columns like Col I and Col J as well).

Comment: I see that the formula is working as expected. Thanks for marking the post as "Best Answer." This effectively lets the volunteer contributor community here know which posts have been successfully answered; and it allows future site visitors to easily find relevant answers related to their own searches. I see that you've typed "Thank you!" in your sheet. Your sheet permission is set to "View only," so I couldn't reply; but you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution can be done using the function `HOUR` to extract the hour of a time column, and then use `IF` and `AND` to do the conditionals, like this:

```
=IF(AND(HOUR(A2) >= 4, HOUR(A2) < 10), "MORNING", IF(AND(HOUR(A2) >= 10, HOUR(A2) < 15), "AFTERNOON", IF(AND(HOUR(A2) >= 15, HOUR(A2) < 20), "EVENING", "LATE")))
```

Comment: The conditions for "AFTERNOON" and "EVENING" return correct values, but condition for "LATE" returns "FALSE". I suppose this can be worked around with a simple replace function.

Comment: Damião, your formula will not work as written. An hour of the day cannot be both greater-than-or-equal-to 20 `AND` less-than 4.

Comment: @NathanBarash  It's true, I adjusted the formula to handle this